# How when I scroll highest and then remove class

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, header, sticky

I have a question about when I scroll highest I want to remove the class that have position fixed because the position fixed will hide my div right, so I need remove it and dont hide my div  when I scroll highest.

May I know can only edit the javascript code to solved it? ty

Here is my codepen link

```
https://codepen.io/WeiKang-Ng/pen/bGxGQwx
```

Here is js code

```
(function(){

  var doc = document.documentElement;
  var w   = window;

  /*
  define four variables: curScroll, prevScroll, curDirection, prevDirection
  */

  var curScroll;
  var prevScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
  var curDirection = 0;
  var prevDirection = 0;

  var header = document.getElementById('site-header');
  var toggled;
  var threshold = 100;

  var checkScroll = function() {
      curScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
      if(curScroll > prevScroll) {
          // scrolled down
          curDirection = 2;
      }
      else {
          //scrolled up
          curDirection = 1;
      }

      if(curDirection !== prevDirection) {
          toggled = toggleHeader();
      }

         prevScroll = curScroll;
      if(toggled) {
          prevDirection = curDirection;
      }
  };

  var toggleHeader = function() { 
      toggled = true;
       if (curDirection === 2 && curScroll > threshold) {
        header.classList.add("nav-on-scroll");
        header.classList.remove("show-nav-on-scroll");
      } else if (curDirection === 1 && curScroll > threshold) {
        header.classList.add("show-nav-on-scroll");
      } else {
        toggled = false;
      }
      return toggled
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add 2 lines to remove class from the header.

1st line removes the class if the user is scrolling up and has not yet reached the threshold.

2nd line removes the class if the user is not scrolling or has scrolled past the threshold.

modify the `toggleHeader` function as follow

```
var toggleHeader = function() { 
    toggled = true;
    if (curDirection === 2 && curScroll > threshold) {
        header.classList.add("nav-on-scroll");
        header.classList.remove("show-nav-on-scroll");
    } else if (curDirection === 1 && curScroll > threshold) {
        header.classList.add("show-nav-on-scroll");
        header.classList.remove("nav-on-scroll");   
    } else {
        toggled = false;
        header.classList.remove("nav-on-scroll");    
    }
    return toggled;
};
```

Comment: bro still no work , I update again [link](https://codepen.io/WeiKang-Ng/pen/bGxGQwx) with follow your code but still no workNow when I scroll up no have position fixed.Btw ty for you reply